# passing a variable through querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net

Input string was not in correct format is the error I am recieving when assiging a value to my mediaID variable. It shows up as an integer and am trying to pass it through a querystring. Any ideas?

```
int mediaID =
    int.Parse(((Hashtable)grd_AllMedia.SelectedRecords[0])["MediaID"].ToString());
Response.Redirect("EditMedia.aspx?MediaID=" + mediaID);
```

Comment: Are you sure ((Hashtable)grd_AllMedia.SelectedRecords[0])["MediaID"] isn't an empty string?

Comment: My idea: create a String variable of `(Hashtable)grd_AllMedia.SelectedRecords[0])["MediaID"].ToString()` first so you can debug... We cannot answer questions like these because we can only guess what's in `grd_AllMedia.SelectedRecords[0]`. Debugging, you should learn it.

Comment: What is the best way to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot.

```
int mediaID =
    int.Parse(((Hashtable)grd_AllMedia.SelectedRecords[0])["MediaID"].ToString());

Response.Redirect(string.Format("EditMedia.aspx?MediaID={0}", mediaID));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
var result = (HashTable)grd_AllMedia.SelectedRecords[0];
if(result != null)
{
   var mediaID = result["MediaID"].ToString();
   Response.Redirect("EditMedia.aspx?MediaID=" + mediaID);


}
```